# passing ng repeat specific object to new html page when clicked apply

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a list of objects in a ng-repeat and when I click a specific item I would like to pass the clicked object to another page and show the object's properties in new html page.

```
    <div ng-include="'src/private/jobseekerHeader/jobseekerHeader.html'"></div> 

<section style="margin-top:100px">

        <div class="bg-overlay1">
    <div class="row text-center">

        <br><br>
        <h4 style="color: white">Build Your Career</h4>
    </div>
</div>

    </section> 

   <br>

 <section>

<div class="container"></div>

  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
  <br>
  <br>
  <h4 style="color: #2b85d4;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -41px;
    font-size: 25px;">Recommended Jobs</h4>


</div>
</section> 


 <section>
<div class="container">

<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3">

<div class="form-group">

<input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">

</div>

    <div ng-repeat="myprofile in viewjobCtrl.profile | filter:search" >
           <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #adb5bc66;
border-radius: 7px;
background: #7080901a;">
                <div class=col-xs-12>
                <div class="col-xs-3">

                <h5>Company</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <h5>:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                <h5>{{myprofile.companyName}}</h5>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class=col-xs-12>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <h5>Title</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <h5>:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                <h5>{{myprofile.jobTitle}}(Exp-{{myprofile.experience}})</h5>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class=col-xs-12>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <h5>Description:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <h5>:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h5>{{myprofile.description}}</h5>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class=col-xs-12>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <h5>Package</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <h5>:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                <h5>{{myprofile.package}}</h5><br/>

                 <h4><a ui-sref="applyJobs" style="background: black;
color: white;
padding: 4px 8px 5px 7px;">Apply</a></h4> 

 <!-- <a ng-href="/apply-jobs/{{myprofile.package}}{{myprofile.companyName}}
 {{myprofile.jobTitle}}(Exp-{{myprofile.experience}}){{myprofile.description}}">Apply</a> 
 -->
                </div>
                </div>

                    </div>
                    <hr>
                   </div>   
</div>
</div>




</section>

<div ng-include="'src/public/indexFooter/indexFooter.html'"></div>
```

check the code once so that u can understand clearly ,, i am getting the code from backend using ngrepeat and i want to display particular data in next html page when clicked apply button

Comment: Post the code here. So people can help you more.

Comment: Can you replace ui-sref="applyJobs" by calling controller method using $state.go("statename", {data to pass})  ?? Is it possible?? or entirely you generating html from server?

Answer (score 0):

use ui-router for angularjs, 
and then on ng-click pass the clicked object to next state.

e.g.

```
$state.go("statename", {data to pass});
```

wrap the above code in a function and you will have what u need.

Comment: check the html code once i have posted just now thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you out

```
   <div ng-include="'src/private/jobseekerHeader/jobseekerHeader.html'"></div> 

     <section style="margin-top:100px">
        <div class="bg-overlay1">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <br><br>
        <h4 style="color: white">Build Your Career</h4>
    </div>
    </div>
    </section> 

    <br>

    <section>

    <div class="container"></div>

    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
   <br>
  <br>
  <h4 style="color: #2b85d4;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -41px;
    font-size: 25px;">Recommended Jobs</h4>


</div>
</section> 


 <section>
<div class="container">

<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-3">

<div class="form-group">

<input type="text" ng-model="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">

</div>

    <div ng-repeat="myprofile in viewjobCtrl.profile | filter:search" >
           <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid #adb5bc66;
border-radius: 7px;
background: #7080901a;">
                <div class=col-xs-12>
                <div class="col-xs-3">

                <h5>Company</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <h5>:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                <h5>{{myprofile.companyName}}</h5>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class=col-xs-12>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <h5>Title</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <h5>:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                <h5>{{myprofile.jobTitle}}(Exp-{{myprofile.experience}})</h5>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class=col-xs-12>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <h5>Description:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <h5>:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h5>{{myprofile.description}}</h5>
                </div>
                </div>
                <div class=col-xs-12>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <h5>Package</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                <h5>:</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                <h5>{{myprofile.package}}</h5><br/>

                 <h4 ng-click="callFromJS(myprofile)">Apply</h4> 

 <!-- <a ng-href="/apply-jobs/{{myprofile.package}}{{myprofile.companyName}}
 {{myprofile.jobTitle}}(Exp-{{myprofile.experience}}){{myprofile.description}}">Apply</a> 
 -->
                </div>
                </div>

                    </div>
                    <hr>
                   </div>   
</div>
</div>




</section>

<div ng-include="'src/public/indexFooter/indexFooter.html'"></div>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.callFromJS = function(myprofile){
    $state.go("applyJobs", {data : myprofile}); 
}
```

Comment: check this updated answer. feel free to send your concerns